# How to start logstash with "systemctl restart logstash" in shell scripts

Tags: shell, elasticsearch, logstash, systemctl

I cannot understand the behavior of "systemctl" in a shell script.

During starting **elasticsearch**, now I try to start **logstash**.

This is what I want to do.

1. delete index already existed
2. delete(rename) the file (test.json) which I want to input **elasticsearch**
3. start logstash
4. locate the target file (test.json) to /data/

I found that, for taking in the target file (test.json) to **elasticsearch** with my conf file (/etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf) , "2" and "4" are needed.

Becasue if I run these commands on terminal, I can created index successfully.

```
 # curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/myindex
 # mv /data/test.json /data/test_.json
 # systemctl restart logstash
 # mv /data/test_.json /data/test.json
```

But every time start **logstash** with those commands on terminal,
I'm tired so I created shell script but the script cannot create index on **elasticserch** successfully. I guess, that means the target file are not input so index is not created. .conf is seems to be right because it works.

here is /data/run_easy_logstash.sh

```
    #! /bin/bash
    curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/myindex
    mv /data/test.json /data/test_.json [2]
    sleep 3
    systemctl restart logstash
    sleep 10 # for waiting logstash started
    mv /data/test_.json /data/test.json [4]
```

systemctl in shell script cannot see the result of [2] and [4]?? why?

here is /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf

```
    input {
        file {
            path => ["/data/test.json"]
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
            start_position => "beginning"
            codec => "json_lines"
        }
    }
    
    #filter {
    #}
    
    output {
        stdout { codec => json  }
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "myindex"
        }
    }
```

I just want to know why it does not work.

Comment: i dont understand what is the point of [2] and [4]

Comment: can you share your script output? I think it will encounter with error.

Comment: Thanks comments. About [2], [4], I thought input file(in this case, /data/test.json) should not appear on target path before starting logstash. So at [2], I rename the input file and start logstash where logstash donesn`t recognize the input file, and at [4] , I create the input file then logstash recognize the file for the first time.

Comment: But I found the .conf may be incorrect because I heard ' codec => "json_lines" ' should not be used at input{} at .conf from web article. I modify ' codec => "json_lines" ' into ' codec => "json" ' and change the format of input file (in this case, /data/test.json) . In my opinion, when you use 'json' codec, the file should has no '\n'. So I change the input format like that.

Comment: Then my .conf works well and 'systemctl' commands in shell script also works well. Sorry, my tilte question had been caused by my .conf. I never expected.